# BroadcastReceiver fires multiple times (PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Why `BroadcastReceiver` was trigger multiple time.

My Sample Project is like below code

**ANDROID MANIFEST**

```
    <receiver
            android:name=".LocationProvideListener"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**BBROADCAST RECEIVER**

```
public class LocationProvideListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationProvideListener";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().matches(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION))
        {
            // react on GPS provider change action
            LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean isNetwork = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            boolean isGPS = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Log.e(TAG, "IsNetwork = " + (isNetwork ? "true" : "false"));
            Log.e(TAG, "IsGPS = " + (isGPS ? "true" : "false"));
        }
    }
}
```

**LOG (WHEN TURN ON LOCATION)**

```
07-22 12:09:47.275  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsNetwork = false
07-22 12:09:47.275  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsGPS = true
07-22 12:09:47.778  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsNetwork = false
07-22 12:09:47.778  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsGPS = true
07-22 12:09:48.115  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsNetwork = false
07-22 12:09:48.115  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsGPS = true
```

**LOG (WHEN ACCEPT PERMISSION)**

```
07-22 12:09:55.412  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsNetwork = true
07-22 12:09:55.412  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsGPS = true
```

**LOG (WHEN TURN OFF LOCATION)**

```
07-22 12:10:04.856  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsNetwork = false
07-22 12:10:04.856  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsGPS = false
07-22 12:10:04.941  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsNetwork = false
07-22 12:10:04.941  22176-22176/com.example.checkLocationProvider E/LocationProvideListener﹕ IsGPS = false
```

Comment: no, I don't in term of its behavior, but I try to solve it out according to my business logic. Also, I have implement some wrapper library of fused location api you can see my example project here 
https://github.com/sattha/Jongz-FusedLocationAPI

Comment: Same problem for me,involed onReceive twice for android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED.

Answer (score 3):

Use below concept for handling multiple broadcast event:

```
private BroadcastReceiver gpsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(action) && action.equals(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
                //Do your stuff on GPS status change
                showDialogHandler.removeMessages(1);
                showDialogHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(1, 2000);
            }
        }
    }
};


private Handler showDialogHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(@NonNull Message message) {
        if (message.what == 1) {
            showDialogHandler.removeMessages(1);

            // do your action
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```