# Intent.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION triggered multiple times

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I register my broadcast receiver **once** (debugged it), but *onReceive()* gets triggered **4 times**.

```
private val locationBroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION == intent.action) {
            val locationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
            val locationEnabled = isLocationEnabled(locationManager)

            //..
        }
    }
}
```

Is there clean way of making sure that receiver gets triggered once on every user action? (GPS toogle on/off in this case)

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554676/broadcastreceiver-fires-multiple-times-providers-changed-action ?

Comment: @DanBaruch That feels very hacky solution for me. Was looking for something more cleaner, if there's any other approach.

Comment: Well, not sure if it will work, but maybe you can unregister your broadcast as soon as you get the intent, do all the logic you need and then re-register it? It's not fail proof but will definitely operate better. If I find any better approach I'll let you know

Comment: Facing same issues, in some devices its trigged 2 time, in other 4 times and in some only once.